# Remove specific words from end of string

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to remove specific words from the end of strings until there are no longer any of these words at the end of the strings.

I tried the following:

```
companylist=['dell inc corp', 'the co dell corp inc', 'the co dell corp inc co']

def rchop(thestring, ending):
  if thestring.endswith(ending):
    return thestring[:-len(ending)]
  return thestring

for item in companylist:
    item = rchop(item,' co')
    item = rchop(item,' corp')
    item = rchop(item,' inc')
```

I am expecting the following results:

```
dell
the co dell
the co dell
```

But I am getting these results instead:

```
dell
the co dell corp
the co dell corp
```

How do I make the results not dependent on the order of the replacement words so my results represent the exhausting of all replacement words from the end of the strings?

Comment: What is `rchop`? Is this a function you have made? Please add the code for that if you did so?

Comment: write rchop with or

Comment: ok included rchop def in my edit

Comment: Why do you say the "end" of the string, when you seem to want to remove words from anywhere in it? (per your expected output)

Comment: nowhere in my expected output did I suggest I wanted to remove anywhere from within the string.  Anyway, I amended the examples to make it more clear what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to remove the last word if it is in a list of other words:

```
import re

string = "hello how are you"
words_to_remove = ["are", "you"]

space_positions = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\ ', string)]
print(space_positions)
for i in reversed(space_positions):
    if string[i+1:] in words_to_remove:
        string = string[:i]

print(string)
```

Which outputs:

```
[5, 9, 13]
hello how
```

If you are only interested in removing the last word, no matter what it is you can use this:

```
import re

string = "hello how are you?"

space_positions = [x.start() for x in re.finditer('\ ', string)]
print(space_positions)
for i in reversed(space_positions):
    print(string[:i], '---', string[i:])
```

Which outputs:

```
[5, 9, 13]
hello how are ---  you?
hello how ---  are you?
hello ---  how are you?
```

The `string[:i]` portion is everything before the i'th space, while the `string[i:]` portion is everything after the i'th space.

Comment: Ugh, you totally misunderstand the question, the OP is asking something totally different

Comment: I see, so its not remove any words, its remove **specific** words. Question title could be better.

Comment: Updated to answer question better.

Comment: this works perfectly =).  Sorry for the confusion before

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

companylist=['dell inc corp', 'co dell corp inc', 'co dell corp inc co']
for i in companylist:
    print(re.sub(r"\W(corp|inc|co)\b", "", i))
```

**Output:**

```
dell
co dell
co dell
```

Comment: I updated my question with a more appropriate explanation.  'the co dell corp inc' would become 'the dell' in your example when I wished to keep ' co' in this string since, once corp and inc are stripped off the end, there is no longer a match of the last word in the string to the words I am trying to strip away

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
companylist = ['dell inc corp', 'co dell corp inc', 'co dell corp inc co']
for idx, item in enumerate(companylist):
    companylist[idx] = item.replace(' co', '')
    companylist[idx] = item.replace(' corp', '')
    companylist[idx] = item.replace(' inc', '')
```

Or thanks to @RoadRunner:

```
companylist = [item.replace(' co', '').replace(' corp', '').replace(' inc', '') for item in companylist]
```

And now both cases:

```
print(companylist)
```

Is:

```
['dell', 'co dell', 'co dell']
```

Comment: Could also just build a new list with `[item.replace(' co', '').replace(' corp', '').replace(' inc', '') for item in companylist]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get it done:

```
companylist=['dell inc corp', 'co dell corp inc', 'co dell corp inc co']    
repList = [' inc',' corp',' corp inc']   # list of all the chars to replace  

for elem, s in zip(repList, companylist):
    print(s.partition(elem)[0])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
dell
co dell
co dell
```

**EDIT**:

Using `list comprehension`:

```
print([s.partition(elem)[0] for (elem,s) in zip(repList,companylist)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['dell', 'co dell', 'co dell']
```

Comment: I updated my question with a more appropriate explanation.  'the co dell corp inc' would become 'the dell' in your example when I wished to keep ' co' in this string since, once corp and inc are stripped off the end, there is no longer a match of the last word in the string to the words I am trying to strip away

Comment: @michael even with your updated list `companylist=['dell inc corp', 'the co dell corp inc', 'the co dell corp inc co']` it returns `['dell', 'the co dell', 'the co dell']` isn't that the desired output?